# Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function Submit(){
  var city = document.getElementById('Arrival').value;
  var hotel = document.getElementById('Hotel').value;
  var people = document.getElementById('travelers').value;
  var days = document.getElementById('day').value;
  var Wifi;
      if ( document.getElementById('Wifi').checked = false)
      wifi = 0;
      if ( document.getElementById('Wifi').checked = true)
      wifi = 10;
  var seat;
          if ( document.getElementById('recline').checked = false) seat = 0;
          if ( document.getElementById('recline').checked = true) seat = 20;
          var meal = document.getElementById('Meal').value;
            var price1 = people * Meal;
            var price2 = people * Recline;
            var price3 = hotel * day;

            document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = 'Your total is ' + ( Arrival + price3 + Wifi + price1 + price2 );

            return false;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Make a Reservation</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="final_project_javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final_project_css.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="Nav">
        <nav>
            <a href="reservation.htm">Make a Reservation</a>
            <a href="contact.htm">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="mailing.htm">Join Our Mailing List</a>
            <a href="busline_home.htm">Home</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
<div> <h1> Mad Men Bus Company </h1> </div>

      <form name="reservation">
          <p>First Name: <input type="text"></p>
          <p>Last Name: <input type="text"></p>

      <p>Arrival City:</p>
            St. Louis <input type="radio" name="Arrival" id="louis" value="40"/></br>
            Milwaukee <input type="radio" name="Arrival" id="milwaukee" value="20"/></br>
            Detroit <input type="radio" name="Arrival" id="detroit" value="35"/></br>


      <p>Hotel Choice:</p>
            Economy<input type="radio" name="Hotel" id="economy" value="50"/></br>
            Standard<input type="radio" name="Hotel" id="standard" value="70"/></br>
            Upscale<input type="radio" name="Hotel"id="upscale" value="120"/></br>

        <p>Number of Travelers</p>
<select id="travelers">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<p>Number of Days</p>
    <select id="day">
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>


        <p>Extras</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="Wifi" value="10">Wifi</br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="recline" value="20">Fully-reclining seat</br>
<div id="Meal">
        <p>Meal Choice:</p>

            None<input type="radio" name="Meal" id="none"/></br>
            Snack<input type="radio" name="Meal" id="snack" value="5"/></br>
            Full Meal<input type="radio" name="Meal" id="fullmeal" value="10"/></br>
</div>


        <p>Special Requests:</p>
        <input type="text" name="SpecialRequests"/>
<div>


</br><input type="button" value="Book My Trip" onclick="Submit">

</div>

<h1>Total</h1>



</form>



  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to run a calculation but javascript does not return anything or work. I have given every variable something to tie back to. I have including their values and I have everything but when I click "book my trip" button nothing happens. Can anyone see why this may be happening?

I want to calculate everything the user chooses and output the cost but the button is not doing anything.

Comment: `if(document.getElementById('Wifi').checked = false)` a single equal sign is *assignment*, not comparison. To compare, use double equals or triple equals.

Comment: You also need to have an element with the id of "total in order to apply the result when you get it working - <h1 id="Total">Total</h1>

Comment: and you can use a ternaryinstead of the if's -  document.getElementById('Wifi').checked  ?
      wifi = 10 : wifi =0;

Comment: Google *javascript equality operators*

Comment: And that's why assignment in an if statement is invalid syntax in python...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in short (why the button does nothing and your code doesn't execute) , Is because the `input[type="button"]` `onsubmit` property is referencing a function (`Submit`) that has not yet.. (according to the DOM) been loaded/defined.

Plus you forgot to add the parentheses **e.g** `<input type="button" onclick="Submit()"/>`

Your code was poorly formatted and lacked the semantics necessary to accomplish the task. I did some heavy refactoring and got this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Make a Reservation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="final_project_javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final_project_css.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="Nav">
      <nav>
        <a href="reservation.htm">Make a Reservation</a>
        <a href="contact.htm">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="mailing.htm">Join Our Mailing List</a>
        <a href="busline_home.htm">Home</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1> Mad Men Bus Company </h1>
    </div>

    <form name="reservation">
      <p>First Name: <input required type="text"></p>
      <p>Last Name: <input required type="text"></p>

      <div id="Arrival">
        <p>Arrival City:</p>
          St. Louis <input checked type="radio" name="Arrival" id="louis" value="40"/></br>
          Milwaukee <input type="radio" name="Arrival" id="milwaukee" value="20"/></br>
          Detroit <input type="radio" name="Arrival" id="detroit" value="35"/></br>
      </div>


      <div id="Hotel">
        <p>Hotel Choice:</p>
          Economy<input type="radio" name="Hotel" id="economy" value="50"/></br>
          Standard<input checked type="radio" name="Hotel" id="standard" value="70"/></br>
          Upscale<input type="radio" name="Hotel" id="upscale" value="120"/></br>
      </div>

      <p>Number of Travelers</p>
      <select id="travelers">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
      </select>

      <p>Number of Days</p>
      <select id="day">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
      </select>


      <p>Extras</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="Wifi" value="10">Wifi</br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="recline" value="20">Fully-reclining seat</br>

      <div id="Meal">
        <p>Meal Choice:</p>
          None<input checked type="radio" name="meal" id="none" value="0" /></br>
          Snack<input type="radio" name="meal" id="snack" value="5"/></br>
          Full Meal<input type="radio" name="meal" id="fullmeal" value="10"/></br>
      </div>

      <p>Special Requests:</p>
      <input type="text" name="SpecialRequests"/>

      <div>
        </br><input type="button" value="Book My Trip" />
      </div>

      <h1 id="Total">Total</h1>
    </form>




<script type="text/javascript">

  document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').onclick = Submit;


  function Submit(){
    var city = Number(document.querySelector('input[name="Arrival"]:checked').value);
    var hotel = Number(document.querySelector('input[name="Hotel"]:checked').value);
    var people = Number(document.getElementById('travelers').value);
    var days = Number(document.getElementById('day').value);
    var wifi = document.getElementById('Wifi').checked === false ?
                0 :
                10;

    var seat = document.getElementById('recline').checked === false ?
                0 :
                20;

    var meal = Number(document.querySelector('input[name="meal"]:checked').value);
    var price1 = people * meal;
    var price2 = people * seat;
    var price3 = hotel * days;


    document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = 'Your total is ' + (city + price3 + wifi + price1 + price2 );

    return false;
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```